# Emulating or Equivilent RPM Validation on Windows

Tags: windows, installation

I'm currently looking at emulating some Linux processes but on the Windows platform.

On our Linux systems we can leverage package manager features to check installed applications for changes since the original installation.

I'm not aware of any equivalent built in feature within Windows Installer or Windows Installer API but thought it worth asking here unless I'm missing something.

I have a bootstrapping installer that contains multiple MSI files and I'd like to run something that will confirm that these installations haven't been changed since they were first installed.

There are many ways to do this manually but I was hoping there was a way to do this leveraging something built into windows rather than developing my own processes.

Answer (score 0):

Some softwares exist to manage and deploy msi installation.
Most of them are meant for professionnal use and can be coupled to Active Directory and GPOs.

Personnaly I know Altiris solutions, or WAPT (http://dev.tranquil.it/wiki/WAPT_-_apt-get_pour_Windows/en : it's designed to work like linux APT system).

The problem is that on Windows systems, software developers have a lot of different ways to make "installers":

- msi for Windows Installers
- InstalShield installers
- custom installers
- ...

No Software will be able to handle them all natively, without customization.

By the way, you may find one that fits you current needs.

Comment: Interesting, not exactly what I was getting at though.  I don't want to manage lots of installations on a network just something on a single box to confirm that an app hasn't been changed on the local machine.

Comment: You have software like filehippo that can check if your apps are up to date, but not really if it has been "changed". What I was saying in my answer is that because there is so many way of installing an app (and I didn't talk about Windows Store apps), it's rather difficult to check all files and and configurations for modifications.

Comment: Sure.  I'm only interested in the app I'm authoring the installer for using WiX.  I guess I'm going to have to go the custom route.